# How to simplify LHS of a linear congruence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

In this video [Number Theory | Chinese Remainder Theorem: Example 2](https://youtu.be/rjZnS2Hwwi0?t=150)

following steps are mentioned

$$42x \equiv 1 \pmod 5\\
2x \equiv1 \pmod 5$$

and
$$
35x \equiv 1 \pmod 6\\
5x \equiv 1 \pmod 6
$$
so on...

How he goes from $42x$ to $2x$ and from $35x$ to $5x$?

If there is any theorem, are there any tricks / techniques to calculate those fast?

Comment: What is $42\bmod 5$? What is $35 \bmod 6$?

Comment: As  suggested in the comments to this video you can start with [Number Theory | Congruence Modulo n -- Definition and Examples](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QjTMbspAjsw) from the same person.

Comment: By the linked Congruence Product Rule: $\bmod 5\!:\ 42\equiv 2\Rightarrow 42x\equiv 2x,$ and similarly for the second one. See all the basic Congruence Rules there.

Comment: In fact $\, 2 = (42 \bmod 5)\,$ is the remainder left on dividing $42$ by $5,\,$ which can be calculated efficiently (in general) by the division algorithm.